Livewire poll stops updating during a function execution
I have a function that makes a few requests to external APIs and takes a little long to finish.
I have a status variable in my livewire component and a poll component updating it in the view, and it works fine.
During the function execution, however, I have a foreach and update the status variable with the progress every iteration, but the frontend stops sending the update ajax to the server, and the progress is not displayed.
How can I make the status update work during the function execution? Any help will be appreciated.
Page:
<x-filament-panels::page wire:poll.750ms="getStatus">
    <form wire:submit.prevent='generate'>
        {{ $this->form }}
        <x-button type="submit" class="mt-4">
            Submit
        </x-button>
    </form>


    <div >
        {{ $this->getStatus() }}
    </div>
</x-filament-panels::page>

Component:
    public $status = 'Ready to start!';

    public function updateStatus($message){
        $this->status = $message;
    }

    public function getStatus(){
        return $this->status . time();
    }

    public function generate(){

// Not relevant code

        foreach (json_decode($result->choices[0]->message->content) as $key=>$person){
            $this->updateStatus('Generating ' . $key. ' of ' . $amount . '.');
        }
// Not relevant code
    }

Im using Livewire 3 with Filament.
